# Why does this code warned unreachable in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, unreachable-code

I was thinking to return a map with several directories list. But the very first caused a warning for me:

```
def enlistFiles() {

    return
        [downloadFolder: downloadFolder.listFiles( new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            boolean accept(File file) {
                return !file.isDirectory()
            }
        })]

}
```

"Code unreachable"

Why?

Comment: Because of optional semicolons, the newline at the `return` line is interpreted as an end of statement. So you have 2 statements : one `return`, then an unreachable map.

Comment: Shame on my head, thanks! :)

Comment: @melix you should post that as an answer. [Damn](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything below line 3 will not be executed. The return key word should not be followed by a line break.
Your code should be:

```
def enlistFiles() {
    return [downloadFolder: downloadFolder.listFiles( new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            boolean accept(File file) {
                return !file.isDirectory()
            }
        })]

}
```